# React Native Android: Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly

Tags: android, react-native, fastlane

My app is running fine on `Android` in debug mode. But in release mode it crashes with this error:

```
com.facebook.jni.CppException: Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly
```

I have enabled bundle in release:

```
project.ext.react = [
  enableHermes: true,
  bundleInRelease: true,
]
```

When I inspect my app bundle I can see `index.android.bundle` in `base/assets` folder. It is also in `build/intermiates/assets`.

I am building my app using fastlane:

```
lane :internal do
  android_set_version_code()
  gradle(task: "bundleRelease")
  supply(track: 'internal', skip_upload_apk: true)
end
```

My `React Native` version is `0.62.2`.

When I try a release with a new RN project it works with same settings.

How can I fix this?

**UPDATE:**

I have fixed the problem by creating a new RN project and moving my source files to the new project.

Comment: I'm facing same issue on react-native 0.65.2, any update?

Answer (score -1):

I also got the same issue, it was due to `enableHermes: true`

change `enableHermes: false` and **rebuild**

Comment: It's helpful to know the issue is related to Hermes, but disabling Hermes isn't really a solution. Did you happen to figure out why Hermes causes this issue?